# Defining models in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, orm, data-modeling

I don't like the way of angular treats models.

On their documentation the single example of creating models
is like this:

```
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
 {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
  charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
 });
```

This method does not provide any relationship between models,
properties or methods can be added with "workarounds" and not
in a standard way like you do in Backbone.

You can't define a relationship between models like you do 
in Backbone with relational [plugin](http://backbonerelational.org/).

Some improvement can be gained using Restangular plugin, but I still
doesn't like how the things are. Everything are focused on how to 
communicate with the Rest API, models and their relationships are
forgotten.

How you will define your models and their relationships in your 
application?

Have you considered to use a Javascript ORM with Angular?

Answer (score 0):

It's not models but more like external resources. I use orm on server side and angular gets already formed data with all needed dependencies. I saw advices to use http://www.getbreezenow.com/ but I think it's overhead for web client side scripting.